# How to map this Json array using ObjectMapper for realm?

Tags: swift, realm, rx-swift, objectmapper

How to map the following Json array using ObjectMapper for realm on RxSwift 3?  please help me. Thank you anyway.

```html
class func getMessagesRequest(parameters: [String: Any]?, headers: [String:String] )  -> Observable<Any> {
    return request(.post,  kGetMsgHistory , parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
        .subscribeOn(MainScheduler.asyncInstance)
        .flatMap {response ->Observable<Any> in
            return response.validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
                .validate(contentType: ["application/json","text/json"])
                .rx.json()
        }

"messages" : 
[
    {
      "drTime" : 1478855430000,
      "messageId" : "59257",
      "options" : {
        "pushBidirectionalUrl" : null,
        "img" : "https:\/\/lh3.googleusercontent.com\/K272HPMCfs6k_zqvvt83pzowaIctVT6TO60kM561CWrOxGjePNZfiU-6H0Zj4YHHv9-f=w300-rw",
        "caption" : "Posters",
        "action" : "https:\/\/details.com?id=com.pomelogames.MarsGame"
      }
    },
    {
      "drTime" : 1478855440000,
      "messageId" : "59258",
      "options" : {
        "pushBidirectionalUrl" : null,
        "img" : "https:\/\/lh3.googleusercontent.com\/K272HPMCfs6k_zqvvt83pzowaIctVT6TO60kM561CWrOxGjePNZfiU-6H0Zj4YHHv9-f=w300-rw",
        "caption" : "Posters",
        "action" : "https:\/\/details.com?id=com.pomelogames.MarsGame"
      }
    },
```

Comment: I think [this](https://blog.hyphe.me/realm-and-alamofire-in-a-effective-harmony/) might be useful to you.

Comment: I can't map it  using Rx:  class func getMessagesRequest(parameters: [String: Any]?, headers: [String:String] )  -> Observable<Any> {
        return request(.post,  kGetMsgHistory , parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
            .subscribeOn(MainScheduler.asyncInstance)
            .flatMap {response ->Observable<Any> in
                return response.validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
                    .validate(contentType: ["application/json","text/json"])
                    .rx.json()
            }

Comment: Are you using Rx? if you do, please mention that in the question.

Comment: added to header

Comment: Can you show me your `Message` class?